# To One-Hot encode or not to One-Hot encode

Tags: data-science, feature-extraction

My data set has the day of the week number (Mon = 1, Tue = 2, Wed = 3 ...)

My data look like this

```
WeekDay Col1 Col2 Target
1       2.2  8    126
6       3.5  4    354
1       8.0  2    322
3       7.2  4    465
7       3.2  5    404
6       3.8  3    134
1       3.6  5    455
1       5.5  8    345
6       7.0  6    442
```

Shall I one-hot encode WeekDay so it will look like this ?

```
WeekDay Col1 Col2 Target  Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su
1       2.2  8    126     1  0  0  0  0  0  0
6       3.5  4    354     0  0  0  0  0  1  0
1       8.0  2    322     1  0  0  0  0  0  0
3       7.2  4    465     0  0  1  0  0  0  0
7       3.2  5    404     0  0  0  0  0  0  1
6       3.8  3    134     0  0  0  0  0  1  0
1       3.6  5    455     1  0  0  0  0  0  0
1       5.5  8    345     1  0  0  0  0  0  0
6       7.0  6    442     0  0  0  0  0  1  0
```

I am going to use Random Forest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, it's preferable to use One-Hot-Encoding, before use Random Forest. If this is only a categorical variable in your dataset then go for One-hot-Encoding. If you use R's random forest then as I know R's library deal with it itself. For scikit-learn that's not the case and you have to one-hot encode yourself. There is a trade off. One-Hot encoding introduces sparsity which is undesirable for tree-based models if the cardinality of the categorical variable is big, or in other words, there are many unique values in the categorical variable. However, Python's catboost deals with categorical variables.

Comment: As far as I know, in RF u don't need OHE.

Answer (score 2):

You should not use one hot encoding since you are using a random forest model. An RF model will be able to find the patterns from label encoding as well and generally RF models perform worse with one hot encoding as they might decide to lost a few days when creating a tree. Also one hot encoding introduces the curse of dimensionality in your data, which is never good.

One hot encoding is better in cases of methods like linear regression or logistic regression, where 1 i.e. Monday might get more importance then 6 i.e. Saturday as these models have a multiplication model on the backend.